# How to fix ' Not Found: /{% static 'anyfile.html, css % } '

Tags: python, django

I am adding the styles and scripts to the templates in Django, the rest of the files are getting added but there are two which the server says 'NOT FOUND'

I tried to run a new local host, and it is still the same.

Not Found: /{% static 'css/all.css' % }
Not Found: /{% static 'css/bootstrap.css ' % }

If this works perfectly, the output should run a nice webpage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is space at closing tag on both css `% }` remove it so tag looks like `%}`